# Collapse menu at the bottom of the stage

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Based on this example

https://gist.github.com/SaiPradeepDandem/95accfa4d8de8b9b3310

I created this simple example code:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle("Slide out YouTube demo");

// create a WebView to show to the right of the SideBar.
        bp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #2f4f4f;");
        bp.setPrefSize(800, 600);

// create a sidebar with some content in it.
        final Pane lyricPane = createSidebarContent();
        SideBar sidebar = new SideBar(250, lyricPane);
        VBox.setVgrow(lyricPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

// layout the scene.
        final BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        StackPane st = new StackPane();
        st.getChildren().addAll(bp, sidebar.getControlButton());
        st.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        VBox vb = new VBox(10);
        vb.getChildren().addAll(st);

        layout.setLeft(sidebar);
        layout.setCenter(vb);

// show the scene.
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles/slideout.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private BorderPane createSidebarContent()
    {
// create some content to put in the sidebar.
        final Button changeLyric = new Button("New Song");
        changeLyric.getStyleClass().add("change-lyric");
        changeLyric.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        changeLyric.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
            {
                System.out.println("Some action");
            }
        });
        changeLyric.fire();
        final BorderPane lyricPane = new BorderPane();
        lyricPane.setTop(changeLyric);
        return lyricPane;
    }

    /**
     * Animates a node on and off screen to the left.
     */
    class SideBar extends VBox
    {
        /**
         * @return a control button to hide and show the sidebar
         */
        public Button getControlButton()
        {
            return controlButton;
        }
        private final Button controlButton;

        /**
         * creates a sidebar containing a vertical alignment of the given nodes
         */
        SideBar(final double expandedWidth, Node... nodes)
        {
            getStyleClass().add("sidebar");
            this.setPrefWidth(expandedWidth);
            this.setMinWidth(0);

// create a bar to hide and show.
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(nodes);

// create a button to hide and show the sidebar.
            controlButton = new Button("Collapse");
            controlButton.getStyleClass().add("hide-left");

// apply the animations when the button is pressed.
            controlButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                {
// create an animation to hide sidebar.
                    final Animation hideSidebar = new Transition()
                    {
                        {
                            setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(250));
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void interpolate(double frac)
                        {
                            final double curWidth = expandedWidth * (1.0 - frac);
                            setPrefWidth(curWidth);
                            setTranslateX(-expandedWidth + curWidth);
                        }
                    };
                    hideSidebar.onFinishedProperty().set(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                        {
                            setVisible(false);
                            controlButton.setText("Show");
                            controlButton.getStyleClass().remove("hide-left");
                            controlButton.getStyleClass().add("show-right");
                        }
                    });
// create an animation to show a sidebar.
                    final Animation showSidebar = new Transition()
                    {
                        {
                            setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(250));
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void interpolate(double frac)
                        {
                            final double curWidth = expandedWidth * frac;
                            setPrefWidth(curWidth);
                            setTranslateX(-expandedWidth + curWidth);
                        }
                    };
                    showSidebar.onFinishedProperty().set(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                        {
                            controlButton.setText("Collapse");
                            controlButton.getStyleClass().add("hide-left");
                            controlButton.getStyleClass().remove("show-right");
                        }
                    });
                    if (showSidebar.statusProperty().get() == Animation.Status.STOPPED && hideSidebar.statusProperty().get() == Animation.Status.STOPPED)
                    {
                        if (isVisible())
                        {
                            hideSidebar.play();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            setVisible(true);
                            showSidebar.play();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

How I can display the collapse menu at the bottom of the stage?

Also is there a way to display the collapsed panel closed when the stage is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle("Slide out YouTube demo");

// create a WebView to show to the right of the SideBar.
        bp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #2f4f4f;");
        bp.setPrefSize(800, 600);

// create a sidebar with some content in it.
        final Pane lyricPane = createSidebarContent();
        SideBar sidebar = new SideBar(250, lyricPane);
        VBox.setVgrow(lyricPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

// layout the scene.
        final BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        StackPane st = new StackPane();
        st.getChildren().addAll(bp, sidebar.getControlButton());
        st.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        VBox vb = new VBox(10);
        vb.getChildren().addAll(st);

        layout.setBottom(sidebar);
        layout.setCenter(vb);

// show the scene.
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles/slideout.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private BorderPane createSidebarContent()
    {
// create some content to put in the sidebar.
        final Button changeLyric = new Button("New Song");
        changeLyric.getStyleClass().add("change-lyric");
        changeLyric.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        changeLyric.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
            {
                System.out.println("Some action");
            }
        });
        changeLyric.fire();
        final BorderPane lyricPane = new BorderPane();
        lyricPane.setTop(changeLyric);
        return lyricPane;
    }

    /**
     * Animates a node on and off screen to the left.
     */
    class SideBar extends VBox
    {
        /**
         * @return a control button to hide and show the sidebar
         */
        public Button getControlButton()
        {
            return controlButton;
        }
        private final Button controlButton;

        /**
         * creates a sidebar containing a vertical alignment of the given nodes
         */
        SideBar(final double expandedWidth, Node... nodes)
        {
            getStyleClass().add("sidebar");
            this.setPrefWidth(expandedWidth);
            this.setMinWidth(0);

// create a bar to hide and show.
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(nodes);

// create a button to hide and show the sidebar.
            controlButton = new Button("Collapse");
            controlButton.getStyleClass().add("hide-left");

// apply the animations when the button is pressed.
            controlButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                {
// create an animation to hide sidebar.
                    final Animation hideSidebar = new Transition()
                    {
                        {
                            setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(250));
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void interpolate(double frac)
                        {
                            final double curWidth = expandedWidth * (1.0 - frac);
                            setPrefHeight(curWidth);
                            setTranslateY(-expandedWidth + curWidth);
                        }
                    };
                    hideSidebar.onFinishedProperty().set(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                        {
                            setVisible(false);
                            controlButton.setText("Show");
                            controlButton.getStyleClass().remove("hide-left");
                            controlButton.getStyleClass().add("show-right");
                        }
                    });
// create an animation to show a sidebar.
                    final Animation showSidebar = new Transition()
                    {
                        {
                            setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(250));
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void interpolate(double frac)
                        {
                            final double curWidth = expandedWidth * frac;
                            setPrefHeight(curWidth);
                            setTranslateY(-expandedWidth + curWidth);
                        }
                    };
                    showSidebar.onFinishedProperty().set(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                        {
                            controlButton.setText("Collapse");
                            controlButton.getStyleClass().add("hide-left");
                            controlButton.getStyleClass().remove("show-right");
                        }
                    });
                    if (showSidebar.statusProperty().get() == Animation.Status.STOPPED && hideSidebar.statusProperty().get() == Animation.Status.STOPPED)
                    {
                        if (isVisible())
                        {
                            hideSidebar.play();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            setVisible(true);
                            showSidebar.play();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This makes it expand 'up' when the button is clicked. It's a little jumpy on the first click, I'm at work so I can't debug that bit of it very extensively, but essentially you just set the custom sidebar object at the bottom of the border pane, and then you switch all the .width and .X methods to be .height and .Y methods instead. With some tweaking I'm sure you could also get it to expand 'down' instead.

Comment: Can I ask you is there a way to drag the panel border with mouse cursor? I would like to change the size with mouse cursor when I drag it.

Comment: There isn't any very simple way to do it, you can change the look of the cursor when you reach the border of the pane, and then listen for a mouse-down event, and while the mouse is pressed, bind the y layout of the mouse to the height property of the pane. There might be a few gotchas in there, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: If it's not too complex can you try to implement this, please?